# Clear $stateParams for specific view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

In my Ionic app I have defined a parameter as null for default in my `home` state. So when this parameter is defined as `true`, some actions are performed, in this case a modal appears.

Problem is, when I switch to another state, and go back, this param keeps it's value as `true`.

How can I clear a specific param for a specific view?

This is the piece of code:

```
if ($stateParams.watchTutorial === true) {
  $rootScope.$broadcast('startTutorial');
  $stateParams.watchTutorial = null;
}
```

Tried to set it to null but didn't work.

To resume, navigating:

Home -> View 1 -> Tap button -> Home (Param: `{watchTutorial: true}`). Great, goes home and modal appears. Keep navigating in home..

Home -> View 2 -> Go back Home (No params specificed), `watchTutorial = true` anyways and modal screen appears. And it shouldn't.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved it thanks to your answer @Andre Kreinbring.

This made the job:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
 function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
   if(toState.name == 'app.home') {
     if(toParams.watchTutorial === true) {
       $rootScope.$broadcast('startTutorial');
       toParams.watchTutorial = false;
     }
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I would listen for the $stateChangeSuccess event and then react on the available information.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
  if(fromState == "[the_state_of_view_2]"){
    toParams.watchTutorial = false;
    //or toParams = {}
  }else{
    if ($stateParams.watchTutorial === true) {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('startTutorial');
      $stateParams.watchTutorial = null;
    }        
})
```

Comment: the event is fired in $scope too.

Comment: First of all, thank you Andre, will this work for other states? Because `home` is the main state, and many back actions go there, I'd rather have a global solution than add every state in this event.

Comment: You can also check `toState` and react if `toState` == "Home"

Comment: Aite, i'll try this code and get back to you, thanks.